# Why isn't this image showing before the AJAX request is sent and hiding on completion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to make a "loading" gif visible while my AJAX request is processing. So I have

```
beforeSend: function () { 
   $('.form-sending-gif').show(); 
   console.log("The beforeSend function was called"); 
}
```

and

```
complete: function () { 
   $('.form-sending-gif').hide(); 
   console.log("The complete function was called"); 
}
```

where the `console.log`s are there for mere testing purposes. For reasons unknown, I've confirmed that both functions are firing and yet the image is not show-hiding as expected. I've typed in `$('.form-sending-gif').show()` to the console to verify that said function does what is supposed to. On page load the image is

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you supply a bit more code? Every looks ok at the moment. How are you firing your ajax

Comment: If you run the function `show()` from the console without ajax thing. does it work?

Comment: @Dvir he states "I've typed in $('.form-sending-gif').show() to the console to verify that said function does what is supposed to" so i assume so. Its a bit weirdly worded.

Comment: Maybe the ajax request is so lightning fast that you don't see it? it takes time to load an image also... unless its preloaded! try delaying the hide fn?

Comment: @Spaceman haha you right. I didn't understand the sentence that's why I asked again.

Answer (score 0):

With out more detail from your question its hard to awsners but ill take a stab anyways.

You could try something like this.

```js
$(function () {

    // On click func
    $('#test').click(function(){
        // Set loading image to display here
        $('#test').text('Greetings')

        // Simulated ajax request(put your ajax here)
        var ajaxCallDfd = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function () {
            ajaxCallDfd.resolve();
        }, 1000);

        // When the ajax is finished Then we display the loaded image.
        $.when(ajaxCallDfd).then(function(){
            $('#test').text('Goodbye')
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"> Hi </div>
```